# .Net assembly loading from UNC path fails without modify rights on 64bit

Tags: c#, python, .net, matlab, python.net

I have a problem with .Net assemblies not being found when I try to load them from a 64 bit process if the user loading the assemblies does not have sufficient access rights.

Loading the same assemblies from a 32 bit process is not a problem and if the user running the 64 bit process is given modify rights the loading is not a problem.

The dll files are located on a file share (I assume it is NTFS, but not entirely sure) and loading from a UNC path.

The dlls are not loaded in a normal .Net program but rather used in Python through Python.Net and in Matlab through the normal Matlab .Net integration. The problem is the same in Python and Matlab, so that suggest that the problem is on the .Net side.

Comment: you need to post your OS/Python/.NET versions and bitness. Maybe you can find equivalent open-source .NET assemblies to reproduce the problem here on SO.

Answer (score 5):

There is a version of [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hcs6az6(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts a `byte[]` containing the file content of the DLL to load.  Using this you can manually load pretty well any .NET Assembly that you can access, whether it's on the local drive, network, compressed, resource, downloaded, etc.

In C# you can use something like this:

```
public static Assembly LoadAssembly(string filename)
{
    var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(content);
}
```

Not even going to try to translate that into Python.NET or Matlab.

Since the file read is not involved with the assembly load directly it won't trigger the security concerns of loading a remote assembly.  Also has the added advantage that the DLL file is never locked longer than it takes to read it fully into memory.  Does take slightly more memory to do however.

Comment: That is probably going to be too low level for Python.NET and definitely not going to work on Matlab. The annoying thing is that it works for 32 bit and it also works for 64 bit as long as the files are on local disk or the access rights include modify rights.

Comment: @oyse Looks like you can access the `AppDomain` from Matlab.  Can't you call `ReadAllBytes` or something?